# FTP - Filename not allowed

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to an FTP server using code based on [this Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

My code looks like this for testing purposes:

```
string ftpUrl = "ftp://" + ftpSite + ftpPath + "test.txt";
//string ftpUrl = ftpSite;

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

StreamReader srcStream = new StreamReader(filePath);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srcStream.ReadToEnd());
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Every time I try to upload the file, I get a "Filename not allowed" error back from the FTP server. If I use an FTP client application like WS_FTP, I'm able to FTP the same file just fine.

Any thoughts on how to correct this? I've already tried setting active/passive FTP mode, keepalive, and binary modes without any luck.

**EDIT**

This is a winforms application - the filename comes in from an OpenFileDialog prompt and the FTP address is based on settings in App.Config.

Comment: Could you please include the full result of the ftpUrl?

Comment: Can you please include where ftpSite and ftpPath are coming from and what values you are using?

Comment: It's an internal server, but follows the format: ftp://1.2.3.4/directory/subdirectory/test.txt

Comment: I'd bet a bunch of rep that the parts of `ftpUrl` are missing separators.

Comment: Have you verified the constructed FTP path (ftpUrl) is accurate and correct?

Comment: @KP - yes, I can FTP to the same directory using WS_FTP.

Comment: @Tim KP is asking about the value of `ftpUrl` as it is constructed in your code.

Comment: @Tim my point is - have you confirmed, through debugging the value of ftpUrl at `runtime`, to ensure it is correct? I understand in theory you can FTP through a FTP application. That's why everyone here suspects there is a problem with your FTP path in code. Can you post what's in your app.config? just replace the server name with MYSERVER if you're worried about privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code, I will say there is a very good chance the constructed FTP URL / path is incorrect, in comparison to what you expect it to be when you manually connect to the FTP site through a FTP client.

If you post your app.config code and how you assign values to `ftpSite` and `ftpPath`, it would be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: I needed to escape the "/"'s in the path...this is what I get for working with C# in a VB.NET shop. ;)

Comment: @Tim Check out [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tf6x8z6) - it is the recommended way to deal with Uris and will take care of almost all that string concatenating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that particular error for many cases.

Most common issue is that the path you are accessing is not valid by the permissions allowed, and using a relative path or changing thew path might get it fixed.